# Find the linear transformation when given the kernel.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Write down a linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^3 \to\mathbb R$ whose kernel is $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3:x + 3y - z = 0\}$.

Any tips, it is the only question on the paper that I cannot tackle. I just don't know what to do for the first part, I know how to calculate nullity.

Comment: There have to be more constraints, otherwise there isn't a unique answer.

Comment: Can't get the image to load with the question, I'll just type it in.

Comment: Just fixed it, R is in reference to the reals.

Comment: Since two non-zero linear functionals are parallel if and only if they have the same kernel, the answers given below are essentialy the only ones possible.

Comment: Good thing the image didn’t load, or I’d be giving you grief for not typing in your question in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the definition of the kernel of a linear transformation: it’s the set of vectors that are mapped to zero. In this case, you have a description of that set as the vectors that satisfy the equation $x+3y-z=0$, but the l.h.s. of this equation describes a linear transformation, so...

Answer (score 1):

The map $f:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ defined by
$$f(x,y,z)=x+3y-z$$
seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Define T((x,y,z))=x+3y-z. It is easy to see that this is a linear transformation. 
So Ker(T)={x+3y-z=0 | x,y,z are real numbers}